# Woocommerce check if filtering products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a conditional function or another solution to check if the products are currently filtered?

Something like this would be great:

```
if( is_filtered() ) echo 'Filters active';
```

Amazing would be if the function returns the number of active filters (or a array) or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to David Chandra Purnama who pushed me in the right direction here's a very simple function to use:

```
function active_woocommerce_filters() {

    // for older WC versions
    // global $_chosen_attributes;

    $_chosen_attributes = WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();

    return count( $_chosen_attributes );

}
```

The function returns the number of active filters so it can be used like this:

```
if( active_woocommerce_filters() ) {

    echo str_replace( '%s', active_woocommerce_filters(), 'There are %s filters active' );

} else {

    echo 'There are no filters active';

}
```

**EDIT:**

As Artur Czyżewski pointed out the `$_chosen_attributes` global variable is not available in his installation. This is most likely due to changes to WooCommerce and probably affect all newer versions, so i've updated the `active_woocommerce_filters` function above.

Comment: This doesnt work for me with storefront theme. I put function in functions.php and tried to use it in one of the template files. It returns 0 no matter if filters are active and visible in url.

Comment: OK, i found the solution - you can use `$_chosen_attributes = WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();` instead of global variable which does not exist in my case.

Comment: @ArturCzyżewski: My answer is pretty old and probably some things have changed in WC. I'll add that as edit/note

Answer (score 3):

You can check using `global $_chosen_attributes;`
WooCommerce "Layered Nav Filters" only displayed if filters is active. you can check the code "includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-layered-nav-filters.php":

```
global $_chosen_attributes;

if ( ! is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && ! is_tax( get_object_taxonomies( 'product' ) ) ) {
    return;
}

// Price
$min_price = isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['min_price'] ) : 0;
$max_price = isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['max_price'] ) : 0;

if ( 0 < count( $_chosen_attributes ) || 0 < $min_price || 0 < $max_price ) {
    /* Your Code Here. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate that's what i needed

Answer (score 1):

**is_filtered()** is a WooCommerce built-in function.

It returns true when filtering products using layered nav or price sliders.
Use case here

```
if ( is_filtered() ) {
   echo esc_html__('Some filters are active.', 'text-domain');
} else {
   echo esc_html__('No filters are active.', 'text-domain');
}
```